# The autoload section of a composer.json file

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I have created a composer library.

I have one folder:

```
Models
```

Inside that is 1 file, it has a namespace declared `TestJames`

In my **composer.json** file I have:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "TestJames": "Models/" }
}
```

Firstly, I have no idea what the psr-0 bit means.
Secondly, I am unsure of the order of bits and bobs.

Is there a documentation specifically for this part, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSR-0 is a standard for autoloading, but it's deprecated (if you can, use PSR-4). See more in [here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/).

For doc about composer autoload look [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading)

```
It seems to be better:
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "TestJames\\": "Models/" }
}
```

Has you executed "composer update"? It creates your vendor directory and you autoload.php file.

Also important is that you require vendor/autoload.php in your execution flow before you try to acces to this class.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I also had to uninstall the previous version as it could no longer see the files of the old type I tried... Thanks